# PipelineSegments.store Build Error with VSTO and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, excel-2007, office-interop

I've created an empty VSTO solution with an Excel 2007 Project.  When I build the solution I get this error:

> Error 1   An error occurred while
>   attempting to persist the data. The
>   message returned is: Could not find
>   the add-in deployment cache file,
>   "C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\VSTA\Pipeline\PipelineSegments.store".
>   Please run AddInStore.Update or
>   Rebuild (or run AddInUtil.exe on the
>   command line).  Also, ensure your code
>   has permission to read this file.

I've googled to no avail.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following these steps fixed it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/ccccfd29-ce29-4aaa-8d89-56c88a1a8dd4